# how to Convert Between Timezones

Tags: unix, datetime, timezone

I execute the following command in Unix

```
$ date --date='06/01/2015 00:00:00' +%s
1433142000
```

when i convert it to date, it is as follows:

```
Date in your timezone*: 6/1/2015, 12:30:00 PM
```

I executed the following command in Mac

```
$ date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "2015-06-01" "+%s"
1433221179
```

when i convert it to date, it is as follows:

```
Date in your timezone*: 6/2/2015, 10:29:39 AM
```

I found this command online to convert to PDT timezone(in my mac):

```
$ export TZ=America/Los_Angeles
$ date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "2015-06-01" "+%s"
1433221424
```

when i convert it to date, it is as follows:

```
Date in your timezone*: 6/2/2015, 10:33:44 AM
```

Unix is my production environment and Mac is my local environment. 
I want to write a script(which will convert my date to timestamp) such that if my prod environment gives 6/1/2015 then, the script which i execute should also give 6/1/2015 instead of 6/2/2015.

My prod(unix) is set in PDT and my local is IST. As mentioned i already tried setting TZ=America/Los_Angeles but still i do not get the same dates.

Please help

Comment: "when i convert it to date" - how do you do that? Please show a short but complete script that demonstrates the problem... it's hard to tell exactly what's going on here, other than that you're 12 1/2 hours ahead of Pacific Time at the moment (and will be 13 1/2 hours when Pacific Time goes back to UTC-8). Are you actually trying to represent a date, or an instant in time? If you're trying to represent a date, I would recommend transporting that as a string (e.g. 2015-01-10) rather than as a Unix timestamp, because you're not trying to represent a timestamp.

Comment: i use this site http://www.timestampconvert.com/?go2=true&offset=-5.5&timestamp=1433221424&Submit=++++++Convert+to+Date++++++   to see the date equivalent to the timestamp. I just want the dates to be same i.e. 6/01/2015 not concerned with the timestamp as i am plotting it on a graph using Grafana, which accepts unix timestamp and reconverts it to date form(yyyy-mm-dd). My script is in my local environment and the Grafana tool is set in production environment. i cant create scripts in my prod.

Comment: Well why don't you just tell your script to use the Pacific time zone instead? Do you understand that it's entirely natural for a timestamp in one date in Pacific Time to be in one date, and the same timestamp to be in a different date in your time zone? You could expand the value you convert to a Unix timestamp so that it's midnight Pacific Time, so it will be 12.30pm on the same day in India, but it would simpler just to use the same time zone (ideally UTC, but hey...) everywhere if you *must* use timestamps to communicate data which is really just meant to be a date.

Comment: i did use this export TZ=America/Los_Angeles in my script but still there is a difference of one day. I have mentioned above also that the timestamp i receive after TZ setting still gets converted to 06/02/2015(seeing the date online).

Comment: No, the value 1433221424 is June 1st in Los Angeles. timestampconvert.com has exactly that: "Date in Los Angeles*: 01/06/2015, 22:03:44". I suspect you were misreading timestampconvert.com.